# Know Someone Who Can Answer, If There's Already An Answer

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

I just noticed that this page element doesn't exist on questions which already have an answer posted:

[image]

Even if the answer was posted just now, even if it's low quality (after all, the system has no way to know if it's the *right* answer, just that it was posted as one), etc.

What if the question isn't really *answered* yet?  Or can be answered better, and one knows somebody who can do a great job of answering it?  Sure, we can edit the existing answer(s), up-vote or down-vote accordingly, and so on.  But it's handy to be able to quickly draw attention to a question among one's colleagues even if someone else has already submitted what they think is an answer.

Can we keep that element on the question until an answer has been accepted?

Comment: I would suggest leaving an altered version of this message on questions *with no upvoted answers*. It could say "know someone else" if an answer is already posted. We don't want to encourage extra answers at some point so I wouldn't suggest leaving it on until an answer is accepted.

Comment: Yes. IMO answers with no votes and not accepted shouldn't really be counted as answers across the site as a whole.